# How to monitor packets using Snort features?

Tags: ios, objective-c, network-programming, ip-address, snort

I want to create a network intrusion detection system for iOS application. The main function is to allow the user to select a home network (maybe prompt them to simply enter the IP address only) and to be able to monitor the packets and if there is anything suspicious- we need to alert user via push notification or email. i wanted to use the features and functions of Snort, an open source network intrusion detection system.

Any Suggestions,Sample code ?! Where to start?

Answer (score 1):

VM's do not have native hardware access, which is necessary for monitor mode.  Maybe IOMMU PCI passthrough or bridged devices might work.  It is probable that it is possible to compile the iOS kernel with a module that works for the wireless nic.  I don't think it's a proprietary chip specific to apple, because a chip with multie technology capabilities in RF wouldn't be cost effective qt all.  I'm just not sure if the filesystem blocks access in the OS framework or whatever.  I have tried to compile linux/iOS ARM packages natively in the shell with the aircrack-ng source, but have not had any luck.  Maybe someone would have better luck actually cross-compiling a package and sideloading it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible for multiple reasons:

1. You wouldn't be able to compile snort for iOS.
2. In order to run snort you have to have the interface (NIC) in promiscuous mode, which I really don't think you can do on an iOS device (iPhone, iPad, etc) but I have never really looked into it, but Apple probably locks this down and restricts this for security purposes so if you could do it you'd likely have to jail-break the device first. It's not even possible to put the wifi card in an Apple laptop into monitor mode, which is similar.
3. There are a lot of dependencies for snort, most importantly the DAQ. You would probably only be able to monitor the wifi interface (even this might not be possible), not the interface used for the cellular network as this is probably a different daq than standard Ethernet nics.

This very likely is not possible on iOS, if it is it would be VERY difficult to pull off and even if you did the use case isn't really good. Even if you could get a daq for the cellular card, I don't know if promiscuous mode even exists and if it did all of the traffic on the cellular network is encrypted, so inspecting this with snort would be pointless. If you could do it for the wifi traffic it's probably not worth the effort honestly, especially since almost all traffic nowadays is encrypted, you'd have to decrypt it first, which certainly isn't possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the view of Johnjg12's comments, I am wondering about your goal. If you want to make a NIDS, you can make it OS independent, anyway. If you want to consider only HIDS that monitors packet destined to it, we don't need it to be in promiscuous mode (a comment to Johgj12's response). so, now it is something to do with Snort on iOS. I am wondering if we can do it on a VM and then turning its promiscuous mode? Having said that I came across a link: https://www.securemac.com/macosxsnort.php